# Workaround for countries that aren't supported by Twilio

Tags: twilio, voip, phone-number, forwarding, countries

The situation is pretty standard: probably there are no CCaaS (Contact Center as a Service) providers that can sell you phone numbers in nearly any country in the world. Lets take Twilio - it doesn't even support all countries in Europe for voice calls.

The technical question sounds like this:

- **What would be the best strategy to operate using Twilio in a country that is not supported by Twilio (you can't allocate a phone number)?**

My thoughts are:

- Buy a phone number from a CCaaS that supports that country and then port to Twilio (but I think you cna only do that in USA).
- Other way would be to use a bought phone number as a forwarder (proxy) to a phone number in Twilio system?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the use cases for Twilio Bring Your Own Carrier (BYOC). If the carrier in the unsupported country supports pointing the number to a SIP DOMAIN, you can have all calls to that number directed toward your unique Twilio SIP Domain.

[Announcing Twilio’s Bring Your Own Carrier (BYOC) Trunking for Programmable Voice](https://www.twilio.com/blog/bring-your-own-carrier)